# javascript beginner onclick event problem

Tags: javascript

I think everything is correct, but why whenever I click the button, nothing happens? I'm using Webstorm and I tried it running with `VSCode` nothing happens either.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Counter</h2>
    <h3>0</h3>

    <button class="increment" id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">+</button>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


function increment() {
    console.log("button clicked!")
}
```

What i think everything is correct, but why whenever i click the button, nothing happens? I'm using webstorm and i tried it running with vs.code nothing happens either.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide us with a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code looks perfectly fine, there may be other factors contributing to not executing your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

your javascript file must always be within a script tag. Another option would be to include everything in your script tag inside index.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Counter</h2>
    <h3>0</h3>

    <button class="increment" id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">+</button>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
<script>
  function increment() {
      console.log("button clicked!")
  }  
</script>
</html>
```